# jQuery and Php variable calling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery and PHP.

I have a `.php` file that contains a variable, for example `var surname = "";`
The problem that I am facing is, I want remotely access it from a `.html` file and give it a value from another variable in the `.html` file.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you said you wanted to get a variable from HTML and send it to the PHP file to change data, that is what the variable 'varfromhtml' is. 
You just need to give it a value you want to send, you can get the value of a div using jQuery eg

```
<div id="div">data</div>
var varfromhtml = $.("#div").val();
```

The variable 'varfromhtml' is now equal to 'h08sahdas', you can mess around with that to get it right for you.

Here is the final script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var varfromhtml = $.("#div").val();

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    action: "myfile.php",
    data: {
        varfromhtml:varfromhtml
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#mydiv').val(data);
    }
});    
</script>
```

Comment: You should explain how this works using comments. They may not have prior experience with `Ajax`.

Comment: Hey @Dermot thanks, for the answer but it did not help me as i have no past experience with Ajax, imma search a bit more about that though :)

Comment: @Dermot if you could explain what exactly is `varfromhtml:varfromhtml` i would apreciate it a lot